# FLUTTER Firestore Creates a new document when merge is used to updata a field

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Iam trying to update a field in the document using `merge:true`.
it fails to update the document not only that i creates a duplicate document of same documentID with only the updated field
 Code

```
    await Firestore.instance
    .collection('QuizProfile')
    .document(id)
    .setData({
  'Score': ['asdfg'],
}, merge: true);
}
```

adding a screenshot here

[image: Original Document created initially]

[image: Duplicate document created after using setData with merge:true]

Comment: It's not possible to create two documents with the same ID in the same collection.  There might be a bug in the Firestore console, so I suggest refreshing the page to check that.  Also be sure to check the exact value of the ID of the document - are there any trailing spaces that we can't see?

Answer (score 2):

> `setData` with `merge:true` will update fields in the document or create it if it doesn’t exists while `updateData` will update fields but will fail if the document doesn’t exist

If the `id` is equal to the original document id in firestore, then you can use `updateData`:

```
   await Firestore.instance
    .collection('QuizProfile')
    .document(id)
    .updateData({
  'Score': ['asdfg'],
});
}
```

Comment: Yes, i could but i have problem with using `updateData`

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: i have posted that issue too [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070167/flutter-firestore-error-performing-updatedata-no-document-found-to-update]

Comment: the field exits but i doesnt update the data it results in `No document to update`

Comment: The document doesn't exists that's why updateData fails, make sure its the same without spaces and try with another document id

Comment: Yes, it was i white space in the document ID, the code is fixed now, Thanks

Comment: @hifaaz Since the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful thank you!