# Flutter Firestore Error performing updateData, No Document found to update

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im using Firestore for mu Flutter project.
I cannot update a field in a document. It results in error (error performing update, No document found)

Code:

```
    await Firestore.instance.collection('QuizProfile').document("20200528-KYUMI").updateData(
      {
        'Slot': 'asdfg',
      },
    );
  }
```

Error message ::

```
E/flutter (18326): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 
PlatformException(Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: 
No document to update: projects/fir-2d2f0/databases/(default)/documents/QuizProfile/20200528-KYUMI, null)
    E/flutter (18326): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
    package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:569
    E/flutter (18326): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
    package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:321
    E/flutter (18326): <asynchronous suspension>
    E/flutter (18326): #2      MethodChannelDocumentReference.updateData 
    package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:41
    E/flutter (18326): #3      DocumentReference.updateData 
    package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:60
    E/flutter (18326): #4      Model.pushscore 
    package:firestoredemo/models/QA_Model.dart:214
    E/flutter (18326): <asynchronous suspension>
    E/flutter (18326): #5      _CustomTextState.initState 
    package:firestoredemo/CustomText.dart:21
```

[Firestore database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MazTY.png)

Comment: Read my answer before before updateData will fail if the document doesn't exist

Comment: Could you throw more light on this Peter? I'm having the same issue. What is your previous answer?